# Textarea not updating in my Markdown Previewer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, react-class-based-component

I've been working on this Markdown Previewer to improve my skills in JavaScript and React and I've run into an issue I can't solve. I don't know if I've just been staring at it too long or what.

Everything loads properly, the only issue is that when I try to type something into the `textarea`, it won't let me change anything in it. It isn't set to read only, so I'm really unsure as to what it is doing this.

Component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      markdown: initialMarkdown
    };
    this.handleChange(this.handleChange.bind(this));
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    try {
      this.setState({
        markdown: event.target.value
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="input">
          <div className="header">Editor</div>
          <textarea
            id="editor"
            value={this.state.markdown}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div className="output">
          <div className="header">Preview</div>
          <div
            id="preview"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: marked(this.state.markdown) }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//Rendering to HTML
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I've scoured a few different threads and subreddits and what not, but I have found nothing to solve my issue. Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`handleChange` is throwing an error when it's called:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

The issue is that the `this` of the class component isn't correctly bound to the callback function so it is simply undefined in the callback.

In the constructor change

```js
this.handleChange(this.handleChange.bind(this));
```

to

```js
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

or convert `handleChange` to an arrow function

```js
handleChange = (event) => {
  try {
    this.setState({
      markdown: event.target.value
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```